# Visualforce with responsive design

Tags: visualforce, mobile, size, lds, responsive-design

I have to make this vfp responsive for 320x480 resolution , cause there is lost content like the following image shows:
[image]

As you can see from bigger resolutions, the content that is lost is most of the right column and the link  from below
[image]

This is my code

```
<apex:page standardController="CampaignMember"  extensions="AdobeSummaryPageController">

    <!-- Display Error Message on Page -->
    <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
    
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
            
                <!-- First Column of Page Section -->
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:panelGrid columns="2" Cellpadding="2">
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Page Name:" style="float:right;" for="PageName"/>
                        <apex:outputLink id="PageName" Target="_blank" value="/lightning/r/Report/{!PageNameId}/view?fv0={!eachCampMem.CampaignId}&fv1={!leadContactId}">{!PageNameCount}</apex:outputLink> 
                        
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Download Name:" style="float:right;" for="DownloadName"/>
                        <apex:outputLink id="DownloadName" Target="_blank" value="/lightning/r/Report/{!DownloadNameId}/view?fv0={!eachCampMem.CampaignId}&fv1={!leadContactId}">{!DownloadNameCount}</apex:outputLink>
                   
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Video Name:" style="float:right;" for="VideoName"/>
                        <apex:outputLink id="VideoName" Target="_blank" value="/lightning/r/Report/{!VideoNameId}/view?fv0={!eachCampMem.CampaignId}&fv1={!leadContactId}">{!VideoNameCount}</apex:outputLink>                  
                        
                        <apex:outputLabel value="YouTube Video Name:" style="float:right;" for="YouTubeName"/>
                        <apex:outputLink id="YouTubeName" Target="_blank" value="/lightning/r/Report/{!YouTubeNameId}/view?fv0={!eachCampMem.CampaignId}&fv1={!leadContactId}">{!YouTubeNameCount}</apex:outputLink>                 
                   
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Internal Search Value:" style="float:right;" for="InternalSearchValue"/>
                        <apex:outputLink id="InternalSearchValue" Target="_blank" value="/lightning/r/Report/{!InternalSearchId}/view?fv0={!eachCampMem.CampaignId}&fv1={!leadContactId}">{!InternalSearchValueCount}</apex:outputLink>
             
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Page Sections Consumed:" style="float:right;" for="PageSectionsConsumed"/>
                        <apex:outputLink id="PageSectionsConsumed" Target="_blank" value="/lightning/r/Report/{!PageSectionsConsumedId}/view?fv0={!eachCampMem.CampaignId}&fv1={!leadContactId}">{!PageSectionsConsumedCount}</apex:outputLink>
                  
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Social Shares:" style="float:right;" for="SocialShares"/>
                        <apex:outputLink id="SocialShares" Target="_blank" value="/lightning/r/Report/{!SocialSharesId}/view?fv0={!eachCampMem.CampaignId}&fv1={!leadContactId}">{!SocialSharesCount}</apex:outputLink>
                     </apex:panelGrid>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>  
                
                <!-- Second Column of Page Section -->
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:panelGrid columns="2" Cellpadding="2">       
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Time Spent on Site (Minute):" style="float:right;" for="TimeSpentonSite"/>
                        <apex:outputText id="TimeSpentonSite" value="{!TimeSpentSiteCount}"/> 
                       
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Form Start:" style="float:right;" for="FormStart"/>
                        <apex:outputLink id="FormStart" Target="_blank" value="/lightning/r/Report/{!FormStartId}/view?fv0={!eachCampMem.CampaignId}&fv1={!leadContactId}">{!FormStartCount}</apex:outputLink> 

                        <apex:outputLabel value="Form Completed:" style="float:right;" for="FormCompleted"/>
                        <apex:outputLink id="FormCompleted" Target="_blank" value="/lightning/r/Report/{!FormCompletedId}/view?fv0={!eachCampMem.CampaignId}&fv1={!leadContactId}">{!FormCompletedCount}</apex:outputLink> 
                        
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Platform:" style="float:right;" for="MobileDesktopView"/>
                        <apex:outputLink id="MobileDesktopView" Target="_blank" value="/lightning/r/Report/{!MobileDesktopViewId}/view?fv0={!eachCampMem.CampaignId}&fv1={!leadContactId}">{!MobileDesktopViewCount}</apex:outputLink>
 
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Device Type:" style="float:right;" for="DeviceType"/>
                        <apex:outputLink id="DeviceType" Target="_blank" value="/lightning/r/Report/{!DeviceTypeId}/view?fv0={!eachCampMem.CampaignId}&fv1={!leadContactId}">{!DeviceTypeCount}</apex:outputLink>
                        
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Content Click:" style="float:right;" for="DeviceType"/>
                        <apex:outputLink id="ContentClick" Target="_blank" value="/lightning/r/Report/{!ContentClickId}/view?fv0={!eachCampMem.CampaignId}&fv1={!leadContactId}">{!ContentClickCount}</apex:outputLink>
                        
                        <!-- added by: charmaine.c.yaun US#1033857 - -->
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Page Pathing:" style="float:right;" for="PagePathing"/>
                        <apex:outputLink id="PagePathing" Target="_blank" value="/lightning/r/Report/{!PageLinkPathId}/view?fv0={!eachCampMem.CampaignId}&fv1={!leadContactId}">{!PageLinkPathCount}</apex:outputLink>
                        <!-- added by: charmaine.c.yaun US#1033857 - end -->
                    </apex:panelGrid>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                
                <!-- Display Link of Report that direct to another VF page -->
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:panelGrid columns="2" Cellpadding="2">       
                       <a href="{!$Site.domain}/apex/AdobeIndividualCampaignMember?ID={!cID}" target="_parent">{!$Label.Adobe_SummaryReport_LinkName}</a>
                    </apex:panelGrid>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>  
                 
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Any idea on how to solve this? I tried with sidebar=false on apex:page tag,but had no luck with that one

Comment: You should look at the [Lightning Design System SLDS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/vf_dev_best_practices_slds_responsive.htm), and be sure the check the [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lightning_design_system) also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `apex:panelGrid`/`apex:pageBlock`/etc if you expect a responsive design. These Visualforce components are *not* responsive; in fact, there's even a checkbox for Visualforce pages that indicate a page is supported on Mobile, and only those can be used in a mobile app. Developers should only enable the checkbox for pages that use a reactive design, meaning SLDS or another responsive framework.

Instead, use the [Salesforce Lightning Design System](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/) by importing via `<apex:slds/>`, and then use SLDS classes to form a responsive "table." (Note that it will actually be a collection of nested `div` elements with various CSS classes that enable reactive functionality).